# can we replace full join with union of left and right join? why not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

can we replace  full join with union of left and right join? if no,why?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Yes.When it comes to the performance full join will be faster bocz other method has to execute three command to achieve this.

Comment: Full join = left join (Union) Right join

Comment: why someone might want to do that? union instead of full join. is there any use case?

Comment: @Flicker, I was just clearing my concepts on joins and its importance

Comment: @VISHMAY completely unrelated comment... you offered a bounty on someone's KendoGrid question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23499645/1544886. Just wondering if you've checked the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'YES' if T1 and T2 are sets (no duplicated rows), otherwise the answer is 'NO'.

```
create table t1 (i int);
create table t2 (i int);

insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t1 values (2);
insert into t1 values (2);

insert into t2 values (3);
```

---

#### FULL JOIN

```
select * from t1 full join t2 on t1.i=t2.i 
order by 1,2
```

---

```
1   (null)
2   2
2   2
(null)  3
```

---

#### UNION

```
select * from t1 left join  t2 on t1.i=t2.i
union
select * from t1 right join t2 on t1.i=t2.i
order by 1,2
```

---

```
1   (null)
2   2
(null)  3
```

---

#### UNION ALL

```
select * from t1 left join  t2 on t1.i=t2.i
union all
select * from t1 right join t2 on t1.i=t2.i
order by 1,2
```

---

```
1   (null)
2   2
2   2
2   2
2   2
(null)  3
```

Comment: I think this is more accurate answer.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if one considered using `union all` instead, then they would get all matching rows twice, so it's not a solution as well.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, UNION ALL will create duplicates for the joined rows

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, yes, that's what I meant with "then they would get all matching rows twice".